# How to use jsr 330 annotation in an "IoC container" independent manner?

Tags: spring, guice, jsr330

Pardon my language if question is not clear. I want to use JSR 330 annotations. And I want to be able switch my DI provider. At present my application has to to know at some point that it has to use spring or google-guice. Is there any way I can avoid this.

Right now I've to call :

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
    "com.package1", "com.package2");
```

to get the app context to get the beans. My understanding is that for google-guice i'll have use google-guice specific code.

Is my understanding correct or I totally missed something.

Comment: You indeed need bootstrapping code. Switching the DI container would consist in changing this bootstrapping code, which is just one or two lines. And you'll probably never do it anyway.

Comment: What is your container and packaging. There are many ways to load the application context without writing code

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @Moles I wanted to avoid ApplicationContext entirely as it is spring based.

Comment: Okay, you should always be able to do that, but what is your packaging so I can help you do that. Are you building a war for instance, or just an executable jar?